# How are these two definitions equivalent?

Tags: graph-theory

Definition in the textbook
[image]

> definition-edge cut is the set of edges which disconnect the graph if
>   we remove it from the edge set of the graph.

How are these two definitions equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

They are not completely equivalent -- for example, consider

```
           5
          / \
 1---2---3---4
```

The set $\{23\}$ is an edge cut according to both definitions (take $S=\{1,2\}$, for example).

The second definition appears to allow $\{23,34\}$ to be an edge cut: removing those edges certainly disconnects the graph. I don't think it is standard to consider $\{23,34\}$ a cut, however -- the definition should be that it is a *minimal* set of edges whose removal will disconnect the graph.

Comment: Do they talk about minimality in the textbook definition?

Comment: they mean that edge having one end in $\overline S$ other in $ S$ will be removed to get a two disconnected components. right?

Comment: did they mean  $\overline S$ and $ S$ form vertices of two different connected components?

Comment: please help me. definition in the textbook is not clear to me. I am not able to study further :(

Answer (score 0):

The first definition defines that if you can divide your graph into two disjoint sets of vertexes.  And the edge-cut as the set of edges that connect these two sets of vertexes.

The second definition defines and edge cut as a set of edges that would disconnect these two sets of vertexes.

Comment: in the first definition, are these $S$ and $\overline S$ are the verices of two different connected components of $G$?